# Maven module cannot install due to compilation error but will compile successfully

Tags: java, maven-2

I have a Maven module called `display`. It is part of a larger reactor chain, and I have added code into a file called `SomeClass.java` within `display` which references `java.text.ParseException`, which is imported without a problem. My code in Eclipse shows no reference or import problems and compiles without a problem. However, when I run `mvn clean install` from the command-line in the parent directory, suddenly `display` is throwing an error as follows:

```
Compiling module xxx.yyy.display
    Validating newly compiled units
        [ERROR] Errors in 'file://path/to/SomeClass.java'
            [ERROR] Line 3: The import java.text cannot be resolved
            [ERROR] Line x: ParseException cannot be resolved to a type
            ...
```

The second line repeats for every reference to `ParseException`. This makes little sense because other modules with references to `java.text.ParseException` compile without problem. I decided to install only this module, so I changed into the `display` directory, and ran `mvn clean install` on just this module. It failed with the same message. I then ran `mvn clean compile`, and **it worked**.

I deleted the SNAPSHOT war from my repository and tried again, and it still failed with the same message. I am wondering why compiling works fine but installing fails during compilation. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Answering" this for anyone who is curious -- the reason was because Google Web Toolkit doesn't support all of the standard Java classes but doesn't provide any message to that effect. Moving the reference to `java.text.ParseException` from a file in the `client` package to one in the `server` package allowed everything to compile correctly.